# sum of four squares is less then one

Tags: probability

You are given four numbers $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and $x_4$ in $[0, 1]$. What is the probability that the sum of the squares of these four numbers is less then one.

Comment: The sum of the numbers or the sum of the squares?

Comment: What does the "volume", that this condition creates, look like?

Answer (score 1):

Let us use some geometrical intuition (this is possible because we have uniform probability and no number has a particular privilege with respect to another in the extraction). Simplify the problem to the case of three numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3$: picking them with uniform probability distribution you are asking what is the probability that $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\leq 1$ with the condition $x_1,x_2,x_3\in[0,1]$. This is basically computing the volume of $1/8$ of a sphere of radius 1 (you are excluding all negative coordinates) over the volume of a cube of edge 1 (which is 1 in any dimension). In four dimensions, analogously, you can compute the volume of the 4D sphere and then exclude the negative coordinates combinations: namely you should divide the volume of the aforementioned sphere by 16. This leads to the final result which should be $\pi^2/32$.